# What does it mean in FORTRAN?

Tags: fortran

What does it mean in FORTRAN?

```
DO 11 I = 1,LGTH1
11 ARRAY(I) = 0.D0
DO 12 I = 1,LGTH2
12 IARRAY(I) = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two `do` loops, in modern Fortran they would look like

```
DO I = 1,LGTH1
  ARRAY(I) = 0.D0
ENDDO

DO I = 1,LGTH2
  IARRAY(I) = 0
ENDDO
```

So, you assign zeros to `ARRAY` and `IARRAY`. You could also write this in vector form:

```
ARRAY(1:LGTH1)  = 0.D0
IARRAY(1:LGTH2) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In this program **11** and **12** are flags(labels). labels specify the last line of the loop.

So the line

`DO 11 I = 1,LGTH1`

mean :

Run the line that starts with the `flag=11` for `LGTH-I` rep.

---

The general form of the do loop is as follows:

```
  do label  var =  expr1, expr2, expr3
     statements
  label continue
```

var is the loop variable (often called the loop index) which must be integer. expr1 specifies the initial value of var, expr2 is the terminating bound, and expr3 is the increment (step).

In cases that statement is a one-line command, we can use this form instead :

```
  do label  var =  expr1, expr2, expr3
  label the-one-line-statement
```